# Manejar período de fechas desde panel

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo un programa, y quisiera saber si puedo controlar las fechas desde un solo panel del formulario principal y que afecte a los demás formularios, pongo la imagen para hacer referencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero controlar las fechas desde la parte donde dice periodo, y afectar a todos los formularios.

Este es código que uso para hacer la parte del periodo:

```
public DateTime[] Periodo(DateTime date)
    {
        DayOfWeek day = date.DayOfWeek;
        int diffLunes = DayOfWeek.Monday - day;
        if (diffLunes > 0)
        {
            diffLunes -= 7;
        }
        DateTime lunes = date.AddDays(diffLunes);

        int diffSabado = DayOfWeek.Saturday - day;
        if (diffSabado < 0)
        {
            diffSabado += 7;
        }
        DateTime sabado = date.AddDays(diffSabado);

        var res = new DateTime[2];
        res[0] = lunes;
        res[1] = sabado;
        return res;
    }
```

El código lo tengo en una clase para poder hacer referencia al código desde cualquier formulario.

Comment: utiliza Interface para pasar datos entre formulario siempre y cuando esten abiertos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar una clase Static y las propiedades que quieras tambien static para que el valor siempre se conserve y los consultes desde cualquier formulario. Tampoco necesitaras instanciarla.

```
public static class MiClase
{
  public static int diffLunes {get;set;}
  public static int diffsabado {get;set;}

}
```